# In Django REST framework, how do you access a field in a table referenced by a foreign key

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have the following models in Django:

```
class campaign(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField('Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField('End Date')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active_start_time = models.TimeField()
    active_end_time = models.TimeField()
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField('Date updated',auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%d | %s | %s' % (self.id,self.name, self.description)

class campaign_product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('product',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField('Date updated',auto_now=True)
    campaign_id = models.ForeignKey('campaign',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=11)
    discount_price = ((1,'Yes'),(0,'No'))
    discounted_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=11,blank=True,null=True)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField('Date updated',auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d | %s' % (self.id, self.name)
```

I also have the following serializer:

```
class campaignProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = campaign_product
        fields = ('product_id', 'campaign_id')
```

And the following view set behavior in the urls.py file:

```
class campaignProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = campaign_product.objects.filter(campaign_id__start_date__lte=datetime.now(),campaign_id__end_date__gte=datetime.now(),campaign_id__active__exact=True)
    serializer_class = campaignProductSerializer
```

My problem is I need to include the name field from the products model in my query results when for instance a request is made on http://127.0.0.1:8000/campaign_product/1/. Currenly this request returns only the product_id and the campaign_id. I tried making the serializer as follows:

```
class campaignProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = campaign_product
        fields = ('product_id', 'campaign_id', 'product.name')
```

But then the service returns the following error:

```
Field name `product.name` is not valid for model `campaign_product`.
```

I event tried using product__name with and without quotes. Without quotes it tells me that there is no such variable, and with quotes it gives the is not valid for model error similar to the above. Heeelp! Getting this extra field is proving to be a pain :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want will need to look something more like this:

```
class campaignProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_name = serializers.CharField(source='product_id.name')

    class Meta:
        model = campaign_product
        fields = ('product_id', 'campaign_id', 'product_name')
```

P.S. As an unrelated side note, it is generally a convention in Python code to name classes with CamelCase, such as `Campaign`, `CampaignProduct`, `Product`, and `CampaignProductSerializer`.

**Edit:** P.P.S. Originally, I had put written the `product_name` field with `source='product.name'`. This was actually due to me looking at the code too quickly and making assumptions based on Django conventions. Typically, with a Django ForeignKey, you would name the ForeignKey field after the model you are linking to, rather than explicitly naming it with `_id`. For example, the `CampaignProduct` model would typically be written with `product = ForeignKey(...)` and `campaign = ForeignKey(...)`. In the background, Django will actually use `product_id` and `campaign_id` as the database field names. You also have access to those names on your model instances. But the `product` and `campaign` variables on your model instances actually return the objects which you are referring to. Hopefully that all makes sense.

Comment: close but not quite there. Now im getting "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product_name` on serializer `campaignProductSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `campaign_product` instance.
Original exception text was: 'campaign_product' object has no attribute 'product'."

Comment: Thanks, on your note about the convention... coming from a java background. Will adjust in future python projects.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I will correct the answer in a minute along with another quick note. Also, as far as style conventions, I would highly recommend reading PEP 8, the Python Style Guide.

Comment: Thanks dude, makes perfect sense. You have even encouraged me to make adjustments according to the conventions you mentioned. Much appreciated!